# Move attributes from one xml file to another via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

So I have an XML file with the following format:

```
[...]
<level1>
    <para id="1"/>
    <image type="photo" artist="Joe"/>
    <para id="2"/>
    <para id="3"/>
    <level2>
        <para id="4"/>
        <image type="pencil" artist="Bob"/>
        <para id="5"/>
    </level2>
    <para id="6"/>
    <image type="oil" artist="Joe"/>
</level1>
[...]
```

The problem is that the image attributes aren't always right, and they don't have a unique identifier. I have another file that has all the correct attributes. I'm trying to write a transform that will remove the incorrect attributes, and then place the correct attributes from my other file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ============================================================= -->
    <xsl:variable name="target" select="document('correct.xml')//image"/>


    <xsl:template match="image">
        <xsl:variable name="vPath1">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="vPath2">
            <xsl:for-each select="$target[ancestor-or-self::*]">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="$vPath1=$vPath2">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$target/@*"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

This successfully removes all of my incorrect attributes, but it doesn't place the correct ones. It seems like my 'if' statement is never hitting, but I know that the paths are the same. What did I do wrong?

my correct.xml looks like this (which is also what the output should look like):

```
[...]
<level1>
    <para id="1"/>
    <image type="pencil" artist="Joe"/>
    <para id="2"/>
    <para id="3"/>
    <level2>
        <para id="4"/>
        <image type="photo" artist="Steve"/>
        <para id="5"/>
    </level2>
    <para id="6"/>
    <image type="oil" artist="Bob"/>
</level1>
    [...]
```

Comment: You verified that `$vPath1=$vPath2` with an `<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$vPath1"/></xsl:message>` etc?

Comment: I'm still fairly inexperienced with xslts, so I hadn't done that. I gave it a try and my $vPath1 is okay, but my $vPath2 just returns 'figure/figure/figure/...'
Any idea where I went wrong in setting that variable?

Comment: Are you using XSL 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Show the code in `correct.xml` + a sample output of your expected result considering the input you provided.

Comment: I'm using XSL 2.0. I've included my desired output (which is the same as my 'correct.xml' file.

Comment: Your input and output examples aren't even close to well-formed. Can you update them so we have something we can work with?

Comment: This expression: `$target[ancestor-or-self::*]` is the same as: `$target` and in the definition of the `vPath2` variable you are concatenating the names of all the elements you select, which are all `<image>` since `$target` is `document('correct.xml')//image`. Thus the resulting string will be `/image/image/image` which will obviously not match `vPath1` which selects the whole tree.

Comment: How then, do I select the whole tree in `$target`?

Comment: Does the structure of "correct.xml" match the structure of the input XML exactly (like it does in your examples)?

Comment: The structures should match. I know that the image xpaths match exactly, but there's a possibility that someone else can add or remove a para.

Comment: My answer should work then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of the 2 XML docs match exactly, you can match the paths using positional predicates. This will ensure that you're comparing unique paths.

Otherwise you'll have to match on id's or something. If that's the case, let me know and I can update my answer to use the `id` (or whatever) attributes when generating the paths.

**XML Input**

```
<level1>
    <para id="1"/>
    <image type="photo" artist="Joe"/>
    <para id="2"/>
    <para id="3"/>
    <level2>
        <para id="4"/>
        <image type="pencil" artist="Bob"/>
        <para id="5"/>
    </level2>
    <para id="6"/>
    <image type="oil" artist="Joe"/>
</level1>
```

**Correct XML** (I named it so_good.xml.)

```
<level1>
    <para id="1"/>
    <image type="pencil" artist="Joe"/>
    <para id="2"/>
    <para id="3"/>
    <level2>
        <para id="4"/>
        <image type="photo" artist="Steve"/>
        <para id="5"/>
    </level2>
    <para id="6"/>
    <image type="oil" artist="Bob"/>
</level1>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (also works as 1.0)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="good" select="document('so_good.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template name="getPath">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name())"/>
            <!--Predicate is only output when needed.-->
            <xsl:if test="(preceding-sibling::*|following-sibling::*)[local-name()=local-name(current())]">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())])+1,']')"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image">
        <xsl:variable name="currPath">
            <xsl:call-template name="getPath"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$good//image" mode="new-attrs">
                <xsl:with-param name="currPath" select="$currPath"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image" mode="new-attrs">
        <xsl:param name="currPath"/>
        <xsl:variable name="goodPath">
            <xsl:call-template name="getPath"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$currPath=$goodPath">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<level1>
   <para id="1"/>
   <image type="pencil" artist="Joe"/>
   <para id="2"/>
   <para id="3"/>
   <level2>
      <para id="4"/>
      <image type="photo" artist="Steve"/>
      <para id="5"/>
   </level2>
   <para id="6"/>
   <image type="oil" artist="Bob"/>
</level1>
```

To help show what's being compared, you can add this `xsl:message` to the "new-attrs" moded "image" template:

```
<xsl:message>Comparing "<xsl:value-of select="$currPath"/>" (currPath) to "<xsl:value-of select="$goodPath"/>" (goodPath). Do they match? <xsl:value-of select="boolean($currPath=$goodPath)"/></xsl:message>
```

You should see messages like: (sorry for the image)

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!  I'll have to take some time to figure out exactly what this is doing, but it's working.

Comment: @Beeblebrox42 - You're very welcome. If you have any questions, let me know.